# PPRINT in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, pretty-print

Emacs Lisp does not seem to have a PPRINT function.  How do you pretty print an S-EXP in elisp the way you can in Common Lisp?

Comment: I see cl-prettyprint will print to the current buffer.  I am looking for something that works with an output stream like Common Lisp's PPRINT does.

Answer (score 27):

Use the `pp` library which is part of GNU Emacs. For example you can use `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` for prettifying an sexp.

Comment: Easiest way is to just use `(pp object)`

Comment: My... that library looks familiar.  Oh yeah, I wrote it. :)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that the result of `cl-prettyprint` is good enough for you, here's how to get its output in a stream.

```
(defun pprint (form &optional output-stream)
  (princ (with-temp-buffer
           (cl-prettyprint form)
           (buffer-string))
         output-stream))
```

Comment: When you are a buffer how can you get cl-prettyprint to replace a defun with its pretty printed version? Can

Comment: Thanks for this. It's weird to me that `cl-prettyprint` doesn't return a string in the first place.